# How to covert a double to an int

Tags: java, int, double

I'm trying to convert a double to an int but I don't get my expected results. Can someone help me?
Here's my code. My expected output is 21 but I keep getting 21.0.

```
double costItem2 = 32.55;
int budget2 = 713;
double totalItem2 = budget2 / costItem2;
totalItem2 = (int) totalItem2;

System.out.println(totalItem2);
```

Comment: 21 equals to 21.0   Thus, there is no problem. It is only display...

Comment: What output do you want if it the budget was 712?

Answer (score 2):

Thats because `double totalItem2` still holds a double even if you cast the result that you're assigning it to an `int`

You have to:

```
int totalItemTemp2 = (int) totalItem2
```

Comment: Or `System.out.println((int)totalItem2);`, just for the record.

Comment: true dat I like to be explicit some times

Comment: @Dolda2000: Well, yes, but if your intent is to work with an `int`, then you really need to make it an `int`.

Comment: @Danatela Not always true.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to format the output yourself. Here is how:

```
NumberFormat numFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####"); // you can have it as #.## if you only want up to two decimal places
double costItem2 = 32.55;
int budget2 = 713;
double totalItem2 = budget2 / costItem2;

System.out.println(numFormat.format(totalItem2));
```

so for example, 123.00 would be printed as 123

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the type of `totalItem2` at runtime like this,

```
double totalItem2 = budget2 / costItem2; // <-- totalItem2 is a double, not int
totalItem2 = (int) totalItem2; // <-- truncates
```

But you could change the declaration to an `int` with a cast like,

```
int totalItem2 = (int) (budget2 / costItem2); // <-- truncates
```

or a `long` with out,

```
long totalItem2 = Math.round(budget2 / costItem2); // <-- rounds, no cast!
```

or an `int` bu using a `float` costItem2,

```
float costItem2 = 32.55f;
int totalItem2 = Math.round(budget2 / costItem2); // <-- rounds, no cast!
```

Answer (score 0):

casting `totalItem2` to `int` will not change the type of `totalItem2`(which will still remain a `double`).

```
int tmpInt = (int) totalItem2;
System.out.println(tmpInt);
```

should fix it.